# Sleep Program Until Keypress

Tags: python, sleep, interrupt, key-bindings, hotkeys

I have the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import keybinder

def Mark(args):
    print "Why, hello!"

keybinder.bind("<Super>m", Mark, "junk")
KEYBINDER.MAIN_LOOP_KEYPRESS()
```

In other words, I would like to make a program which sleeps silently in the background until a key combination is pressed anywhere in the system. Keybinder seems like a good way of getting the keypress, but I'm not sure how to do the sleeping part implied by the final line. It seems as though importing a large framework like GTk would be overkill for this application and I'd prefer to avoid a busy loop.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just:

```
while not key_pressed:
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: It feels a little like a busy loop, which I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: It uses 0% of CPU time - why not?

Comment: Also, I did test this by inserting it in the last line of my code and it did not work: the specified keybinder function never got called.